# THREE.js obj loader with face selection

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on adapting the object loading example on the THREE.js example page to allow for the loaded objects to have their faces selected and colored. My general strategy has been to follow the steps outlined [here](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Mouse-Click.html).

However, since I am not using THREE.geometry objects, I am having trouble piecing together this strategy with the obj loader code.

I currently have ray intersection working so I know when I am clicking on the object, I am just having trouble coloring the faces. I know I need to apply: `vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors` to the obj material and thats where I'm stuck.

My current obj loading code is as follows:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
loader.load( path, function ( object ) {
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
          var faceColorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff00ff, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors } );
          child.material = faceColorMaterial;
          child.geometry.addAttribute( "color", new THREE.BufferAttribute( new Float32Array( 3 * 3 ), 3 ) );
          child.geometry.dynamic = true;
        }
    } );
    scene.add( object );
    targetList.push(object);
}, onProgress, onError );
```

And my detection and coloring code:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 1 );
vector.unproject( camera );
var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );
var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( targetList, true );

if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
  var colorArray = intersects[0].object.geometry.attributes.color.array;
  var face = intersects[0].face;
  colorArray[face.a] = 1;
  colorArray[face.a + 1] = 0;
  colorArray[face.a + 2] = 0;
  colorArray[face.b] = 1;
  colorArray[face.b + 1] = 0;
  colorArray[face.b + 2] = 0;
  colorArray[face.c] = 1;
  colorArray[face.c + 1] = 0;
  colorArray[face.c + 2] = 0;
  intersects[0].object.geometry.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;
}
```

When I run this, my object is black and when I click the faces, they do not change color.

How can I alter my code to allow for the changes to be colored when selected?

Answer (score 0):

`OBJLoader` should be returning `BufferGeometry` objects, which don't use `FaceColors`. `BufferGeometry` can use `VertexColors` to assign colors to a face, but you need to ensure the `colors` attribute is applied to the `BufferGeometry`. If you do have a `colors` attribute, then you're in luck, because `OBJLoader` gives you unique vertices for each triangle.

When `intersectObjects` returns, the `Face3` should have `a`, `b`, and `c`, which I believe should be indicies into the `mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array`, but they'll also be indices into the `mesh.geometry.attributes.color.array` array.

```
var colorArray = intersects[0].object.geometry.attributes.color.array,
    face = intersects[0].face;
colorArray[face.a] = 1;
colorArray[face.a + 1] = 0;
colorArray[face.a + 2] = 0;
colorArray[face.b] = 1;
colorArray[face.b + 1] = 0;
colorArray[face.b + 2] = 0;
colorArray[face.c] = 1;
colorArray[face.c + 1] = 0;
colorArray[face.c + 2] = 0;
intersects[0].object.geometry.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;
```

This should turn a particular face red. But I can't stress enough that this will only work if your geometry has a `colors` attribute, and your material is using `THREE.VertexColors`.

Comment: My geometry does not have a colors attribute, how do I go about fixing that? I have updated vertexColors to THREE.VertexColors for my material

Comment: I added the colors attribute to the buffergeometry however, I am still not seeing anything happen when I intersect

Comment: I have updated my above code to reflect the changes you have suggested.